# Rails not saving /permitting value of nested forms to be stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

My `_feature.html.erb` looks like-

```
<%= error_messages_for(@project) %>
<div class="card m-auto shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
  <div class="card-body">
  <%= form_for [@project, @feature], class: "form-group inline", remote: true  do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.hidden_field :feature_token_id, value: auto_generate_id %>

      <%= builder.hidden_field :category, class: "form-control", value: category_value %>

      <%= builder.label :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= builder.label :desc, "Description" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :desc, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= builder.fields_for :task, remote: true do |form| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :name %>
          <%= form.text_field :name, required:true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <%= form.check_box :completed, class: "form-check-input" %>
          <%= form.label :completed %>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :user_id, "Select the User to Assign this task:" %><br>
          <%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name %>
        </div>

      <% end %>

      <%= builder.submit class: "btn btn-primary m-2" %>

  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my FeaturesContrller is ->

```
class FeaturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project

  def index
    @features=Feature.all
  end

  def new
    @feature=Feature.new
    @feature.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @feature=@project.features.new(feature_params)
    binding.pry
    if @feature.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

    private
    def set_project
      @project=Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def feature_params
      params.require(:feature).permit(:name, :desc, :category, :feature_token_id, tasks_attributes: [:name])
    end
end
```

But while I try to save the form values only the Feature table gets updated but the tasks_attributes remain unpermitted instead of permitting them, what is the wrong thing I am doing?

And here is the log from `pry`

```
    13: def create
    14:   @feature=@project.features.new(feature_params)
 => 15:   binding.pry
    16:   if @feature.save
    17:     redirect_to @project
    18:   else
    19:     render "new"
    20:   end
    21: end

[1] pry(#<FeaturesController>)> feature_params
Unpermitted parameter: :task
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"ayann", "desc"=>"uhi", "category"=>"Current Iteration", "feature_token_id"=>"38378"} permitted: true>
[2] pry(#<FeaturesController>)>
```

And If I exit from pry only Feature table is updated with new value not Task table!(Log looks like)

```
  Feature Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `features` (`name`, `desc`, `feature_token_id`, `project_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `category`) VALUES ('ayann', 'uhi', '38378', 4, '2019-08-20 07:55:27', '2019-08-20 07:55:27', 'Current Iteration')
```

My `feature.rb` model  ->

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end
```

And `task.rb` model ->

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

what is the reason that my nested model task is not being saved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `_feature.html.erb` file, in building the form for accepting nested attributes for tasks. The line `<%= builder.fields_for :task, remote: true do |form| %>` tries to build a form for the relation `task`, but the `Feature` model has a `has_many` relation with tasks. Changing that line to `builder.fields_for :tasks` will pass the parameters as expected (as `tasks_attributes` and not `task_attributes`, which is probably being sent currently).

Comment: that seems to work, I will check and update.. can you please tell me how can I add a button in the main form to dynamically add another `fields_for`  fileds in my form

Comment: You would have to do that using event in JavaScript. A simple way could be to assign the tasks form an identifiable id, and dynamically change its behaviour on the basis of a button's click (A button which says "Add more tasks"). 
Another way would be to use a gem like Cocoon or one of its alternatives mentioned in this blog: https://ruby.libhunt.com/cocoon-alternatives

Comment: yes I cannot/ would not use any gems , how can I implement on button "add task" click - can you provide any code example or reference

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://jyrkis-blogs.blogspot.com/2014/06/adding-fields-on-fly-with-ruby-on-rails.html